# In the crystal report how to make percentages in the basis of various contents

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to make a crystal report,in where I create a group in the basis of district.Now I want to insert some of data from the database like as a parentage dependent on various content.How I can make this query in crystal report.
For example -- the percentage of 'sum of age' in the basis of male learners in one text box and the percentage of 'sum of age' in the basis of female learners in another text box.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a group for the Age
2. Create a summary fields (One for Male, One for female) that counts age (Attach a formula for summary that check say gender = 'M' for male)
3. Create two formula that computed the % from the summary fields (Male, female)
4. Place this formula on your relevant text box

Comment: Text box should be on the Group footer of the Age group